# Perl module Apache-PageKit installation testing error

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl

I have installed the Apache::PageKit module and while testing this module it shows below error.

But the availability of module, using below it is there

```
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ perl -MApache::PageKit -e1
bash-3.2$

bash-3.2$ ./t/TEST -start-httpd
[warning] setting ulimit to allow core files
ulimit -c unlimited; /usr/bin/perl /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/TEST -start-httpd --documentroot '/install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/eg'
/install/others/apache2/bin/httpd  -d /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t -f /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/httpd.conf -D APACHE2 -D PERL_USEITHREADS
using Apache/2.2.25 (prefork MPM)

waiting 60 seconds for server to start: .Syntax error on line 24 of /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf:
Can't locate loadable object for module Apache::URI in @INC (@INC contains: /tmp/apache_test /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/blib/lib /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/blib/arch /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/ /install/others/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl /install/others/lib/CPAN/lib /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//mod_perl.pm line 14\nCompilation failed in require at /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf line 28.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted\t(in cleanup) Can't locate loadable object for module Apache::URI in @INC (@INC contains: /tmp/apache_test /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/blib/lib /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/blib/arch /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/ /install/others/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl /install/others/lib/CPAN/lib /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//mod_perl.pm line 14\nCompilation failed in require at /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf line 28.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf line 28.\n
[  error]
server has died with status 255 (t/logs/error_log wasn't created, start the server in the debug mode)
sh: line 1: 25604 Terminated              /usr/bin/perl /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/TEST -start-httpd --documentroot '/install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/eg'
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ perl -MApache::URI -e1
bash-3.2$
```

Here line 24 is `<Perl>`. so pagekit could not able to parse this line.

```
bash-3.2$ vi /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf
# WARNING: this file is generated (from /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/conf/extra.last.conf.in), do not edit
# generated on Thu Jul 11 08:09:38 2013
# 01: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestConfig.pm:961
# 02: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestConfig.pm:979
# 03: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestConfig.pm:1452
# 04: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestConfig.pm:1564
# 05: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestRun.pm:502
# 06: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestRunPerl.pm:107
# 07: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestRun.pm:713
# 08: /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/TestRun.pm:713
# 09: /install/others/Apache-PageKit-1.14/t/TEST:72

# Apache::Reload is very very helpfull during development,
# but it is not required. So install it and uncomment
# the following lines
#
# PerlModule Apache::Reload
# PerlInitHandler Apache::Reload
# PerlSetVar ReloadAll On

# <Perl >
<Perl>

# It is not necasary to preload this modules, but it helps
```

How can i resolve this.

Thanks
Shanmugam A.

Hi,

Thanks for your reply, now i have installed Perl 5.8.8, Apache 2.2.25, Modperl 2.0.8 and Apache2::PageKit for this combination i have below error while starting the apache.

```
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ /install/others/apache2/bin/apachectl start
[Mon Jul 15 11:28:10 2013] [error] Can't locate loadable object for module Apache::Constants in @INC (@INC contains: /install/others/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/ /install/others/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /install/others/lib/perl5/site_perl /install/others/lib/CPAN/lib /dso/dsoapps/iesdev/qtngsas70/DSOMP/lib /dso/dsoapps/iesdev/qtngsas70/DSOMP/bin. /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 . /install/others/apache2) at /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//mod_perl.pm line 14.\nCompilation failed in require at /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//ModPerl/P2.pm line 2.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /install/others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//ModPerl/P2.pm line 2.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 3.\n
[Mon Jul 15 11:28:10 2013] [error] Can't load Perl module ModPerl::P2 for server (null):0, exiting...
```

Note: Here i am setting up from Unix to Linux server.
In Unix it was the combination of Apache 1.3.27, mod_perl 1.27 Apache::PageKit And in Apache Configuration below is the additional part added with default

```
#################################################################
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
  PerlModule ModPerl::P2
  <Location /P2>
     SetHandler perl-script
     PerlHandler ModPerl::P2
     PerlSendHeader On
  </Location>

  PerlModule ModPerl::P1
  <Location /P1>
     SetHandler perl-script
     PerlHandler ModPerl::P1
     PerlSendHeader On
  </Location>

  PerlModule Apache::DBI
#### Entered by Tom Frizzell April 25 2008
  PerlFixupHandler Apache::SIG

</IfModule>

###############################################################
# PageKit setup
PassEnv ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID ORACLE_USERID TAPEMON_HOME TAPEMON_LIB

<Perl>
use lib "/chshttp/prod/qtngsas70/DSOMP/lib";
</Perl>

SetHandler perl-script
PerlSetVar PKIT_ROOT /chshttp/prod/qtngsas70/DSOMP/www
PerlSetVar PKIT_SERVER test

PerlHandler +Apache::PageKit
<Perl>
        Apache::PageKit->startup('/chshttp/prod/qtngsas70/DSOMP/www', 'test');
</Perl>

PerlInitHandler +Apache::Reload
# Error Handling
PerlModule Apache::ErrorReport
PerlSetVar ErrorReportHandler display
```

This Configuration i have changed all Apache::PageKit to Apache2::PageKit and respective source code as well. I have just copied the files ModPerl::P1 and ModPerl::P2 from Unix server to Linux. But it shows the error as above.

Shall i know how to resolve this.

Thanks

Hi,

When i access the page is shows 500 internal error. and the apache log says that (Can't locate object method "is_main" in the perl module Apache::SIG).  Shall i know how to resolve this.

```
bash-3.2$ more error_log
[Sun Jul 14 09:38:12 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 14 09:40:01 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 16 06:39:59 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.8.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 16 06:41:01 2013] [error] [client 10.191.51.22] Can't locate object method "is_main" via package "Apache2::RequestRec" at /install/
others/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi//Apache/SIG.pm line 14.\n
```

my updated apache configuration is

```
#################################################################
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
  PerlModule ModPerl::P2
  <Location /P2>
     SetHandler perl-script
     PerlHandler ModPerl::P2
#    PerlSendHeader On
      PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
  </Location>

  PerlModule ModPerl::P1
  <Location /P1>
     SetHandler perl-script
     PerlHandler ModPerl::P1
#    PerlSendHeader On
      PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
  </Location>
  PerlModule Apache::DBI
  PerlFixupHandler Apache::SIG  
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b %{SIGPIPE}e"
</IfModule>

###############################################################
# PageKit setup  TAPEMON_HOME TAPEMON_LIB
PassEnv ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID ORACLE_USERID 

<Perl>
    use mod_perl2;

    # It is not necasary to preload this modules, but it helps
    # to find errors in your instalation.

    use Apache2::URI ();
    use Apache2::Cookie ();
    use Apache2::Request ();
    use Apache::SessionX ();
    use Apache2::Util ();
    use Compress::Zlib ();
    use File::Find ();
    use HTML::FillInForm ();
    use HTML::Parser ();
    use HTML::Template ();
    use XML::LibXML ();

    use Apache2::PageKit();
    use lib "/dso/dsoapps/iesdev/qtngsas70/DSOMP/lib";
</Perl>


SetHandler perl-script
PerlSetVar PKIT_ROOT /dso/dsoapps/iesdev/qtngsas70/DSOMP/www
PerlSetVar PKIT_SERVER test
PerlHandler +Apache2::PageKit
<Perl>
        Apache2::PageKit->startup('/dso/dsoapps/iesdev/qtngsas70/DSOMP/www', 'test');
</Perl>

PerlInitHandler +Apache2::Reload
# Error Handling
PerlModule Apache2::ErrorReport
PerlSetVar ErrorReportHandler display
```

Shall i know how can i resolve this

Thanks
Shanmugam A.

Comment: Is mod_perl installed on that system?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apache-PageKit works only with mod_perl1, but not with mod_perl2 (the latter would use Apache2::URI, not Apache::URI). So you should probably look for an alternative, or if you really need this module, then you have to find a way to install Apache1 and mod_perl1 on your system.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, shall i know where can i download the mod_perl-1.24_01. since i tried with mod_perl-1.27, but no luck. And in Apache-PageKit Requirement says need mod_perl-1.24_01.

Comment: Don't use Apache1+mod_perl1. Try Apache2+mod_perl2+Apache2::PageKit instead.

Comment: Hi Rezic, Thanks for you help. I have installed Apache2+mod_perl2+Apache2::PageKit. And while starting apache it shows above error(Can't locate loadable object for module Apache::Constants in @INC). Help me to resolve this.

Comment: `Apache::Constants` is mod_perl1. mod_perl2 is using `Apache2::Const`. You have to rewrite this, and also other things, see http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/porting/compat.html

Comment: Thanks Rezic, now i can able to start the apache. But while accessing the page it says 500 internal error. and the error log says that (Can't locate object method "is_main" in the perl module Apache::SIG). Shall i know how to resolve this. I also attached updated configuration as above.

Comment: Apache::SIG seems also to be a modperl1 thing. So you have to rewrite this functionality, too.

Comment: Thanks Rezic, Now i can able to start apachi and UI pages are working fine. But the Session are not working. so the pages are not working as expected, i have posted this in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859403/apache2-pagekit-session-meintenance-issue). Any help please.

Comment: Hi Rezic, want to hear from you. Thanks

Comment: No idea. Probably you should ask directly the Apache2::PageKit author.